# about us page on magento does not change after editing

Tags: php, html, magento, content-management-system

I have problem about magento.
Why my about us page on magento does not change after editing?
even though I have changed through the admin page and when priviewed it has changed. but in reality on the web it still displays the previous about us that hasn't been changed.

Thank's

Comment: did you clear the cache, also if external cache like redis or varnish is used.. please try clearing them too.

Comment: @SunilVerma oke thank's the page is turned out to be in a static block